# Google Maps API: How to catch "DIRECTIONS_ROUTE: NOT_FOUND"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps keeps throwing this error:

[image]

I'm fully aware that it can't geo-code one of the stops that I've given it, but I don't know how to *catch* the error and stop it from logging. Otherwise it goes to my error-catcher and spams me with emails.

My code is basically this:

```
this.directionsService.route(directionsRequest, (response: google.maps.DirectionsResult, status: google.maps.DirectionsStatus) => {
    if (status === DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        // HANDLE OK RESPONSE
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.warn("google.maps.DirectionsService.route failed", "Error:", err, "Segment:", seg, "Request:", directionsRequest)
})
```

where `this.directionsService` is an instance of `google.maps.DirectionsService`. And if you need to see it, the request object looks like this:

```
const directionsRequest: google.maps.DirectionsRequest = {
    origin: origin,
    waypoints: waypoints.map(stop => ({location: stop})),
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: TravelMode.DRIVING,
}

if (seg.pickupTime) {
    const pickupTime = new Date(seg.pickupTime);
    if(pickupTime > Date.now()) {
        // Prevent "departure_time is in the past. Traffic information is only available for future and current times."
        directionsRequest.drivingOptions = {
            departureTime: new Date(seg.pickupTime),
        }
    }
}

if(this.props.distanceUnit === 'KM') {
    directionsRequest.unitSystem = google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
} else if(this.props.distanceUnit === 'MI') {
    directionsRequest.unitSystem = google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
}
```

The part I don't get is that I've put a `.catch` on there already, and that is indeed hit when the geocoding fails *but* it *also* logs an error anyway.

That error happens somewhere in Google's library:

[image]

Is there any option to disable it?

---

I'm loading the library like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${encodeURIComponent(apiKey)}&libraries=places,drawing
```

Comment: ~what version are you using? weekly or quarterly?~

Comment: just checked and looks like this is hard coded in there for some reason... can you file a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207 and link it here?

Comment: @jpoehnelt Filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191928195 thanks!